# Is there a specific way to format strings for logging?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I added the `logging` library to a script to incorporate logging, and started getting these warning messages about string formatting. Not sure what's the culprit as it's not causing the script to break or anything.

Warning message is: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Here's how I'm setting up the configuration in the script, and the line that the warning message points to:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='output.log', format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('Getting data from: ', api_endpoint)
```

Is the configuration setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

Your log statement doesn't actually include an argument? Change it to: `logger.info('Getting data from: %s', api_endpoint)`

Comment: how do I do this with logger.exception(e, 'some additional info here')